# Eclipse type inference issue

Tags: eclipse

Running on Eclipse Oxygen, and *Create local variable* (Cmd-1) results in `Object` instead of the inferred type.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object x = get("test", o -> o.length());
}

public static <A, B> B get(A target, Function<A, B> func1) {
    B result = func1.apply(target);

    return result;
}
```

I would expect it to create `x` as `int`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: o.length() returns an int. So the actual type would be Integer, not String. IntelliJ does it right.

Comment: Oops, right.  Just corrected it.  Eclipse bug?  Can anyone else reproduce?